# How to get text and corresponding tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a text, contains HTML tags something like:

```
text = <p>Some text</p> <h1>Some text</h1> .... 
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
```

I parsed this text using `BeautifulSoup`. I would like to extract every sentence with corresponding text and tag. I tried:

```
for sent in soup:
    print(sent.text) <- ok
    print(sent.tag) <- **not ok since NavigableString does not has tag attribute**
```

I also tried  `soup.find_all()` and stuck at the same point: I have access to text but not original tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `tag` use [`name`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name) to get the elements tag name:

```
for tag in soup.find_all():
    print(tag.text, tag.name)
```

*Use the parameter `'html.parser'` to avoid behavior of standard parser `lxml` that will slightly reshape the structure and wraps partial HTML in  `<html>` and `<body>`*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p>Some text</p><h1>Some text</h1>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all():
    print(tag.text, tag.name)
```

##### Output

```
Some text p
Some text h1
```